Bitcoin SE has two new Moderators! Please give a warm welcome to Stephen and Nick!
One of our Christmas presents had still been in transit, but on 5th of January it arrived: We've got two new moderators!





As you might have noticed, Stephen and Nick had already stepped up before their appointment to help push things into the right direction. They could be seen welcoming new users, as well as reviewing, editing, answering, and commenting. Now after accepting a moderator role on the site and being appointed, they are familiarizing themselves with the new perspective they have on the site, but have already started to help out with moderator flags and representing our community on the Stack Exchange network.
Thanks again to the moderators that have stepped down, David Perry, ThePiachu, David Schwartz, D.H., and Turbo, for their huge contributions to Bitcoin.SE and the Bitcoin community. We wouldn't have such a marvelous collection of Questions and Answers without you, and would consider ourselves lucky to have you continue contributing!
I'm looking forward to sharing the moderation responsibilities among the three of us in the future. It is my hope, that we will now have enough manpower to tackle a few issues that had been on the backburner for a while, i.e. that we will be able to not only help maintain Bitcoin.SE, but to work with the other users to push for some improvements and growth.
As always, we would like everyone to bring forth their ideas and concerns here on Meta, as well as contributing to the discussion of the topics that are already there.
Feel free to come by our chat-room, the Bitcoin Lounge, to get help, discuss questions, and ideas, or for idle conversation. A weekly chat is held in the Bitcoin Lounge on Monday 20:00 (8pm) GMT, but you will find people hanging out there most days of the week.
Please give a warm welcome to Stephen and Nick!
All the best, and a great start into 2015 everyone!

Congratulations indeed!  Thanks to all three of you!
